# Is the chemistry behind the "Anoxic Filter" actually real? [Pond/Aquarium Denitrification]

Tags: everyday-chemistry

In the Aquarium hobby, there are two methods to remove NO3 from your water:

- Plants
- Water changes

There are a handful of people and companies that sell porous biological media that claims to create low-oxygen zones inside of it for anaerobic bacteria to grow. That seems to be snake oil.

There has emerged another proposed method called "Anoxic filtration". It involves mixing baked clay kitty litter with an iron rich substrate called Laterite to create a "biocenosis basket" and placing it inside the filter. It is said that this will convert nitrate to nitrogen gas. Below is a synopsis of how it is claimed to work:

[image]

> **Zone A**
>
> Negative charges in the cat litter in the baskets begin to attract molecules of ammonia (NH4) towards its centre. As these molecules pass through zone A nitrifying bacteria (nitrogen cycle bugs) will grab one ammonia molecule and four oxygen molecules; they will then excrete one nitrate molecule.
>
> There is now far less oxygen but there will still be enough for the nitrogen cycle to continue so we will continue to journey with the ammonia molecules into zone B.

> **Zone B**
>
> As more and more ammonia is converted to nitrate, the ammonia level drops even more and the nitrate level rises. So much oxygen has been used in the process that this area can no longer be called truly aerobic, (oxygen rich), but there is still a little oxygen left to sustain some nitrifying bacteria so we will follow the remaining ammonia as it journeys into zone C

> **Zone C**
>
> The ammonia is still being pulled remorselessly toward the centre of the basket but almost all oxygen in the water has already been used. The nitrogen cycle, as we know it, ceases. Nitrification cannot occur if dissolved oxygen levels fall too far below about 2 mg/L and it will be lower than that in zone C where facultative anaerobic heterotrophic bacteria live.
>
> A facultative anaerobic heterotroph can easily make use of the three oxygen atoms and leave just the nitrogen atom which is initially dissolved in the water but will migrate out of the basket and gas off to the atmosphere.

[Full article on Anoxic Filtration](http://www.mankysanke.co.uk/html/anoxic_filtration.html)

[image]

### Questions:

- Is this method of nitrification actually possible?

There is an [article](https://aquariumscience.org/index.php/8-9-1-biocenosis-reactor/) by a hobbyist with a BA in Chemistry that is dedicated to refuting the entire idea:

> The science behind anoxic denitrification of nitrate to nitrogen gas dictates that biocenosis clarification baskets and plenums simply cannot work.

I don't know if I trust the article though because it reads more like a hit piece toward the person who came up with the idea.

I'm looking for clarity on this topic from someone outside of the aquarium/pond hobby.

Comment: I would feel more confident about it if they had not described ammonia as NH4

Comment: @Waylander I believe the NH4 depiction is because at *that* stage the NH3 has *ostensibly* become positively charged.

Comment: The idea that positive ammonium ions are attracted to the negatively charged center is wrong. While there may be negative charges, it is overall neutral, balanced by positive charges.

Comment: Playing with anaerobic environment may lead to forming dangerous nitrites and sulfane.

Comment: @MikeCiffone  if that is the case then they should be refering to ammonium ions

Comment: Denitrification happens in natural anoxic environments due to the right bacteria exploiting available nitrate in the absence of significant amounts of molecular oxygen. This question however is about whether such a process can be exploited in the suggested design of aquarium filter, which may not be a question for this site.

Comment: This may be more appropriate at Biology SE.